# HTML How to fit some cells to content others to rest of available space in row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that I wish to have the following attributes:

1. The table has a set width imposed by a parent element, 500px for the sake of argument.
2. No line-breaking in cells, only one line per cell.
3. Some cells should align their width with the width of their content.
4. The rest should consume the rest of the available space in the row.

I have managed to achieve this without criteria #2 (no line-breaking). When I try to apply no line-breaking the table just becomes insanely wide overflowing the parent container.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/marpal/705p9pqj/.

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="small">OS</td>
      <td class="small">User</td>
      <td class="large">Long Text 1</td>
      <td class="small">Date</td>
      <td class="large">Long Text 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="small">Ubuntu</td>
      <td class="small">Admin</td>
      <td class="large">This is a test text that should stretch until it is finally truncated, at least I think that that is the correct use of the word truncated. Not to mention the spelling, how the hell do you spell truncated? It feels right though.</td>
      <td class="small">2016-02-14</td>
      <td>This is the next long text that should be truncated into one line and the overflow hidden from the world.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

div {
  width: 500px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.small {
  width: 1%;
}

td.large{
  //white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the last criteria (no line-breaking), while keeping the size limit imposed by the parent DIVs width, purely through CSS or will I need to calculate widths dynamically with JavaScript? I would like to avoid this since I think it's ugly and not always super dependable, especially since this table will be updated dynamically during run-time.

Also, how can I get the date to fill a whole cell without line breaks?

Comment: If the width of the table is smaller than the *unbroken content* then this is expected behaviour. Other than removing the no line-breaking requirement I very much doubt if there is a CSS solution...or a JS one for that matter. If it's too wide...it's too wide.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This actually makes things easier since now I have some basis for decisions.